# Titanium: Memory leak in hello world application

Tags: android, memory-leaks, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I have the following basic Titanium Alloy application:

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello, World</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
function doClick(e) {
    Alloy.createController('foo', {}).getView().open();
}

$.index.open();
```

**foo.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window>
        <View class="container">
            <Label id="label">Some text in the foo controller!</Label>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**foo.js**

```
$.foo.addEventListener('close', function () {
    $.destroy();
    $.off();
});
```

I then monitored the amount of memory the Android emulator was using DDMS, based on the instructions provided here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Managing_Memory_and_Finding_Leaks

When the application started the number of objects was: **32,188**

When I click the button, and then close the new window by pressing back, and click "cause GC" the number of objects increases to: **32,332**

I do this again, it increases to: **32,478**

Open and close the window about 8 more times, and it increases to: **34,481**

and so on.

Why is this the case and how do I fix this memory leak?

Comment: it is not a memory leak. Cleanup only happens whenever the OS feels like it, not immediatly.

Comment: Also, use `<Window onClose="closeCb">` instead of manually adding it ;)

Comment: Another also, you don't need to put a function on the `$` scope, just use a function and call that function.

Comment: But I explicitly clicked the  "Cause GC" button. Shouldn't cleanup happen then? I realised I did not make this clear in question. Edited.